# Why a class related to a different package can access an class of another package?

Tags: java, package

**A.java**

```
package a;
class A {

    void f1()
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

---

**B.java**

In same folder as of A.java and class files are generated in the same folder.

```
package b;
class B
{
    new A().f1();
}
```

I am new to package concept. My question here is even though they are not in the same package how can B create the object of A?

Comment: `function` is for JavaScript. Your **A.java** class won't even compile.

Comment: please mention package structure of your classes and access specifiers (public or default ) of your classes clearly then only it can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use public class declaration it goes to `public access level`. Public classes can be accessed by different packages by using `import a.A;` or providing the complete class name `new a.A().f1()`.

Comment: Classes with the default access level cannot be accessed by classes outside of that package, you're confusing default with public http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

B will [import (or can use fully qualified name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) the class A from other package if it has to use it. importing enables the classes in other packages to see the classes from a different package. But this can be further find-tuned by using [scoping](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/scope.html).

If both are in the same folder and not using any packages explicitly then they both are in the **default** package. **And you no need to explicitly import the classes while using them if they are in the same package.**

Comment: I want to know how class A is visible to B?

Comment: May be you are not using packages and both the classes are defined in the same package. if not then you should compulsorily use "import". The code will not compile otherwise.

Comment: The scenario here is A.java and B.java are in same folder.Now I have not used any package yet I can create object of class A in class B how?

Comment: http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/ Read how access levels works in java.

Answer (score -1):

You should know access modifiers in java. If your class is public ,it can be accessed anywhere simply by importing it.

Please go through below link for better understanding

http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/

Answer (score -1):

There is something called import in Java which you can import into current package and access methods or members as long as they are public(visible across package) or protected (visible to sub-classes)